# Search function issue in linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, iterator

I am having trouble with the search function implementation for my linked list class. It doesn't print what i want, infact it prints nothing at all even if the data is in the list. Where did i go wrong?

My main:

```
#include "DList.h"
int main(void) {
    DList<int> list;
    DList<int>::const_iterator it;

    cout << list.size() << endl;
  list.push_front(30);
    list.push_front(10);
    list.push_back(100);
    list.push_front(22);

    list.print();
    it = list.begin();
    while (it != list.end()) {
            cout << *it << endl;
            it++;
    }
    DList<int>::iterator it2 = list.begin();
    while (it2 != list.end()) {
            *it2 = *it2 + 1;
            it2++;
    }
    it = list.begin();
    while (it != list.end()) { 
            cout << *it << endl;
            it++;
    }

    list.search(11);
    list.search(100);
    cout << list.size() << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Linked list class :

```
    void erase(iterator it);
    void erase(iterator first, iterator last);

    iterator search(const T& data) {

            }
```

current output:

```
0
22
10
30
100
22
10
30
100
23
11
31
101
4
```

Comment: You say it doesn't print out anything, but you've written out the output. Please strip your question down to the most relevant parts so people don't have to scour the code to determine the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Debugger.  Use the debugger.  The debugger will help you find out how your program *actually* flows.  You can execute each statement singly, *watching* values of variables.  Very useful.  A lot more productive than using StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

In

```
iterator search(const T& data) {
        iterator it = begin();
        iterator notIt = end();
        while (it.curr_ != back_) {
                if (*it == data)
                    cout << "found it" << endl;
                        return it; <-- right here!!!!
                ++it;
        }
        cout << "not in list" << endl;
        return notIt;
}
```

check the `return it;`. In spite of the indentation appearances, it is not inside the body of the `if` because the `if` has no body. As a result this `return` statement is always reached and always returns.

Cleaning up the formatting makes this really obvious:

```
iterator search(const T& data)
{
    iterator it = begin();
    iterator notIt = end();
    while (it.curr_ != back_)
    {
        if (*it == data)
            cout << "found it" << endl;
        return it;
        ++it;
    }
    cout << "not in list" << endl;
    return notIt;
}
```

Goofy indentation helps no-one, least of all the programmer. I recommend using a code formatter. One may come built into your IDE.

The solution is to use curly brackets to enclose the `return` statement.